# Want String in XML body no other strings

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a function that can return me xml with a tag but i want I hustget the string which i passed not any other tag in a body can i edit the function.

```
 [ServiceBehavior]
    public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public string Greet(string name)
        {
            return "Hello ," + name;
        }
    }
 public class ConsoleMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
 public Message CreateMessage(Message message)
        {

            MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            var messageCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
            Console.WriteLine(messageCopy.ToString());
            return buffer.CreateMessage();

        }
}
```

XML 
Actually I want Only string in body no other tag is it possible..

```
{<s:Envelope xmlns:s="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">; <s:Header>  
 <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http:/…;   
 </s:Header> <s:Body>   
 <GreetResponse xmlns="tempuri.org/">; <GreetResult>Hello ,wasif</GreetResult>   
 </GreetResponse> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about where the data goes: the message header or the message body that's being exchanged between your client and the WCF server.

To do that, you can either use a Data Contract or a Message Contract. These are, as the name suggests, contracts between the client and host (so you need them on both sides) that the information will be exchanged within a particular data structure embedded in the message.

So on the host, where you'd declare your public interface, inside you'd declare a Data Contract with Data Members to which you'd give names. Something like this:

```
public interface IHostInterface
{
[OperationContract()]
MessageStructure HostConnect(MessageStructure inMsg);
}

[DataContract()]
public class MessageStructure
{
private string HeaderString = null;
private string BodyString = null;
[DataMember(Name = "TextSection", Order = 0)]
public string Text {
    get { return HeaderString ; }
    set { HeaderString = value; }
}

[DataMember(Name = "BodySection", Order = 1)]
public string BodyString {
    get { return BodyString ; }
    set { BodyString = value; }
}
//constructors

public MessageStructure(string HeaderValue, string BodyValue)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderValue))
        HeaderString = HeaderValue;
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BodyValue))
        BodyString = BodyValue;
}
}
```

Then when you want to send a request from the client, or response from the host, you'd use the something like this:

```
public class HostInterface: iHostInterface
{
    public MessageStructure HostConnect (MessageStructure inStruct)
    {

    String RequestHeaderText = inStruct.Text;
    String RequestBodyString = inStruct.BodyString;

    String ResponseHeaderText ="cat";
    String ResponseBodyText ="dog";

    MessageStructure outStructure = new MessageStructure(ResponseHeaderText,ResponseBodyText);
    return outStructure;
```

Here's a link to a MSDN explanation of data contracts

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx